# I need to find an open spot in the calendar (MYSQL) and allocate that time and date to a job/work order

Tags: mysql

I need to find an open date time in the future and allocate that time in the calendar for that employee based on his/her worktimes Thanks in advance

I have a calendar table, employee(recourse) table ,employee working times and jobs (with Duration)

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Subject` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `DateField` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `EndDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `TimeField` time DEFAULT NULL,
   `EndTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
   `job_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `recourse_employee_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1902 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `rc_resources_employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categoryid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `Job_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Job_Subject` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job_Description` mediumtext,
  `Job_Start_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job_End_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job_Duration` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job_Start_Time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job_End_Time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job_employee` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`Job_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1875 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `work_hours` (
  `wh_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recourse_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `wh_day_of_week` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `wh_start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `wh_end_time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`wh_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Edit your question to have better formatting. This is unreadable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a calendar table with dates and times, The jobs table have all the open jobs the resource table has employees and the work hours table have the times during the week that the recourse is working, I have to allocate a time and date for the job to be done by the resource during certain hours of the week.

Comment: find and open space in the calendar to book a job against for the resource to do, and inset the entry into the database based on the duration of the job. when a next job is allocated the same process should happen and to make sure the recourse does not have any double or overlapping entries in the calendar